# Cassandra atomic reads/writes within a single ColumnFamily

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra's front page http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/ states that:

> Cassandra guarantees reads and writes to be atomic within a single ColumnFamily.

What exactly does that mean?
It sounds like it means that batch_insert() and batch_mutate() of **two different rows, in the  same CF** is atomic and if the operation on one of the rows fails, the whole operation fails. but it sounds too good to be true... Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

I have an answer from Jonathan Ellis, Cassandra maintainer:

> It's correct, if understood correctly.
>   We should probably just remove it
>   since it's confusing as written.
>
> What it means is, if a write for a
>   given row is acked, eventually,
>   *all* the data updated *in that row* will be available for reads.  So no,
>   it's not atomic at the batch_mutate
>   level but at the
>   list level.

Answer (score 2):

I found this confusing too.  I think the statement that update of all columns in a single row is atomic would be a lot clearer, putting the emphasis on the row.